# CSS conflict when using iFrame

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe

## Overview

Hi there,

I run a website for my Football Team on Wordpress.
I recently used a software to register and create a card for every member of my Football Team. **Since this registration is made outside my website, I used an iFrame to include it**.

However I noticed the **topbar/menu items are not showing up correctly** in the iFrame on my website, but perfectly fine on the software link.

I checked the code through Chrome and found out **there's a line of CSS that's setting the menu's items' display option to None**.
The problem is I can't find the CSS on Wordpress, so I think it's the CSS of the software's website.

## Question

What am I missing?

Is there a way to fix that CSS?

Or have I setup the iFrame wrong?

Or is it maybe a conflict with my website's CSS?

## Screenshots

[My Website, not working](https://www.gscris.it/gscris2019/tesseramento/)

[image: Software's website]

[Software's website, working](https://app.softwaretessere.it/index.aspx?name=Anagrafica&mode=0&tab=tabs-1&key=b4f85bf113e22eb7c00eb0aba4dd20fd)

[image: My Website]

CSS Line

[image: CSS line]

## Edit

Here's the full code for the iFrame:

```
< script language = "javascript"
type = "text/javascript" >
function iFrameHeight() {
    var h = 0;
    if (!document.all) {
        h = document.getElementById('blockrandom').contentDocument.height;
        document.getElementById('blockrandom').style.height = h + 60 + 'px';
    } else if (document.all) {
        h = document.frames('blockrandom').document.body.scrollHeight;

    }
} < /script>

< div > Tesseramento al Torneo Campioni di Amicizia < /div> < iframe onload = "iFrameHeight()"
id = "blockrandom"
name = "iframe"
src = "https://app.softwaretessere.it/index.aspx"
width = "300%"
height = "1000"
scrolling = "no"
align = "top"
frameborder = "0" >
Questa scelta non funziona correttamente in quanto il browser utilizzato non supporta gli Inline Frames < /iframe>
```

Comment: but I think iframe never override on parent code ... maybe you have additional JS or CSS files ?!

Comment: @Alex I've added the entire code for the iFrame, there's a few Js